# Statistical inference: Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

---

The Text:

The manager of a company has accumulated for years the results of a test of aptitude to do some work with it. It seems plausible to suppose that the results of the aptitude test are Normally distributed with a mean $\mu = 150$ and $\sigma^2 = 100$. The test is passed to $25$ individuals of the company. What is the probability that the sample mean is between 146 and 154?

So in this chapter we discussed Chebyshev's inequality in class so assumed it's the one that I'll be using to solve this question.

Here is my approach:

The Chebyshev inequality is written as:

$$P(\mu - k\sigma < X < \mu + k \sigma) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$

X in my situation is the sample mean thus the mean of the sample mean is $\bar{X} = \mu$ and the variance of the mean is $Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ thus its standard deviation is $\sigma_{\bar{X}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

$$P(\mu - k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < X < \mu + k \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$

$$P(\mu - k\sigma_{\bar{X}} \leq X \leq \mu + k \sigma_{\bar{X}}) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$

$$\sigma_{\bar{X}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{10}{\sqrt{25}} = 2$$

$$k\sigma_{\bar{X}} = 4$$ thus $$k = 2$$

finally

$$P(146 \leq X \leq 154) \geq 0.75$$

Is my approach and answer right ? I'm not hunderd percent sure after seeing this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316073/using-chebyshevs-inequality) where $\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}$ was considered the number of standard deviation units instead of $k$ alone.

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality is used when you have no information on the distribution. If you are told that the distribution is Normal, you can improve on Chebyshev's inequality and provide an accurate answer.

Comment: So should I use the Z score approach in this situation after calculating the mean and standard deviation of the sample mean ?

Comment: Yes, that's a very good approach.